# Memory leak when using matplotlib.collection.LineCollection

Tags: python, memory-leaks, matplotlib, guppy

I am using the following code to create a collection of color coded line plots:

```
for j in idlist[i]:
    single_traj(lonarray, latarray, parray)

plt.savefig(savename, dpi = 400)
plt.close('all')
plt.clf()
```

where:

```
def single_traj(lonarray, latarray, parray, linewidth = 0.7):
    """
    Plots XY Plot of one trajectory, with color as a function of p
    Helper Function for DrawXYTraj
    """
    global lc
    x = lonarray
    y = latarray
    p = parray

    points = np.array([x,y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

    lc = col.LineCollection(segments, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Spectral'), 
                            norm=plt.Normalize(100, 1000), alpha = 0.8)
    lc.set_array(p)
    lc.set_linewidth(linewidth)
    plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
```

Somehow, this loop uses a lot of memory (> ~10GB), which is still being used after the plot is saved. 
I used hpy to look at memory usage

```
Partition of a set of 27472988 objects. Total size = 10990671168 bytes.
Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
    0 8803917  32 9226505016  84 9226505016  84 dict of matplotlib.path.Path
    1 8888542  32 711083360   6 9937588376  90 numpy.ndarray
    2 8803917  32 563450688   5 10501039064  96 matplotlib.path.Path
    3     11   0 219679112   2 10720718176  98 guppy.sets.setsc.ImmNodeSet
    4  25407   0 77593848   1 10798312024  98 list
    5  89367   0 28232616   0 10826544640  99 dict (no owner)
    6   7642   0 25615984   0 10852160624  99 dict of matplotlib.collections.LineCollection
    7  15343   0 16079464   0 10868240088  99 dict of
                                            matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform
    8  15327   0 16062696   0 10884302784  99 dict of matplotlib.transforms.Bbox
    9  53741   0 15047480   0 10899350264  99 dict of weakref.WeakValueDictionary
```

At this point the plot is already saved, so all matplotlib related objects should be gone... But I cant "find" these objects, which means I don't know how to delete them.

EDIT:

Here is a stand-alone example which reproduces the leak (savefig throws an error for some reason but isn't relevant anyway):

```
# Memory leak test!

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as col

def draw():

    x = range(1000)
    y = range(1000)
    p = range(1000)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
    ax = plt.gca()   
    ax.set_aspect('equal')


    for i in range(1000):
        if i%100 == 0:
            print i
        points = np.array([x,y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
        segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

        lc = col.LineCollection(segments, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Spectral'), 
                                norm=plt.Normalize(0, 1000), alpha = 0.8)
        lc.set_array(p)
        lc.set_linewidth(0.7)
        plt.gca().add_collection(lc)

    cb = fig.colorbar(lc, shrink = 0.7)
    cb.set_label('p')
    cb.ax.invert_yaxis()
    plt.tight_layout()

    #plt.savefig('./mem_test.png', dpi = 400)
    plt.close('all')
    plt.clf()


draw()

a = input('Wait...')
```

The draw() function should delete all plt objects, but they still use up memory after the function is called. I just check it with top/htop!

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your hpy dump that the memory hog consists of a large number of `matplotlib.path.Paths`. This may be due to your variable `lc`. Have you tried `del lc`? It may be that `plt.close` is not (at least should not be!) able to delete them, as they are in your global variable `lc`.

Comment: I have tried that `del lc`plus `del cb`. I also tried not using a global variable at all and just putting the `single_traj` function directly in the loop. But I still get the same memory result... I really don't understand what's going on...

Comment: Could it be delayed GC for some reason? Have you tried `gc.collect()`. I think the full mantra would be `plt.clf(); plt.close('all'); gc.collect()` in that order. Also, it helps a lot in debugging, if you can make a self-sufficient minimal example of the problem so that we can try it ourselves!

Comment: I tried gc.collect(). Nothing... I will try to make a self-sufficient example. Might take me a little because this problem is embedded in a class method.

Comment: One more: You aren't using `IPython`, are you? Because it creates some references of its own which may prevent GC happening.

Comment: I am using iPython, but the same problem occurs if I run it as a regular script. I will try to reproduce the error in an self-sufficient example today

Comment: I added an example to my original post above. Watch out, it uses about 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: if you call `draw` multiple times does it keep consuming more memory?